# Syntax Error in Preprocessor Macro Code

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

I am trying to write some code for a macro which returns the length of a string, and am attempting to implement it using BOOST_PP_WHILE. The code stems from the fact that a character at a position specified by `position` of the string represented by a macro argument `foo` may be obtained by `#foo[position]`. Compiling using either MSVC or Intel C++ results in similar syntax errors; if you could point out why the code is generating these syntax errors and how I would rectify code, it would be greatly appreciated. **I know that the errors are caused by the code within the `PREDICATE` macro, but any expression I attempt to use within it barring `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM` results in a compile-time error.**

**Errors:**

```
prog.cpp:47:1: error: pasting "BOOST_PP_BOOL_" and ""\"Hello, World!\""" does not give a valid preprocessing token
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:47: error: ‘BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM_2_1’ was not declared in this scope
```

As one would expect, the line numbers are not very useful since both point to the line at which the macro `MACRO_STRLEN` is called.

**Code**

Below follows the source listing in which I attempt to implement the macro which I describe.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/while.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

#define TEST_STRING0 "Hello, World!"

#define MACRO_IS_NULL_IMPL(x, position) \
    #x[position] == '\0'

#define MACRO_IS_NULL(x, position) \
    MACRO_IS_NULL_IMPL(x, position)

#define PREDICATE_D(string, position) \
    MACRO_IS_NULL(string, position)

#define PREDICATE(n, state) \
    PREDICATE_D( \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, state), \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, state) \
    )

#define OPERATION_D(string, position) \
    ( \
        string, \
        BOOST_PP_INC(position) \
    )

#define OPERATION(d, state) \
    OPERATION_D( \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, state), \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, state) \
    )

#define MACRO_STRLEN_IMPL(string) \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( \
        2, 1, BOOST_PP_WHILE(PREDICATE, OPERATION, (string, 0)) \
    )

#define MACRO_STRLEN(string) \
    MACRO_STRLEN_IMPL(string)

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    printf("String length: %d.\n", MACRO_STRLEN(TEST_STRING0));
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Compiling under gcc 4.3.4 produces an additional error that might be of some use - see my edit.

Comment: Strange that an error should arise as a result of pasting two arguments together...I tried modifying the body of the PREDICATE macro, but the same errors result. I am having trouble understanding why BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM works without problems but MACRO_IS_NULL does not.

Comment: Error messages above edited to reflect new error messages generated after OP's edit to code.

Comment: Sorry about that - when I viewed the edit I think I may have ended up undoing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this - http://codepad.org/aT7SK1Lu
Its still a compile-time strlen, and would be likely much faster to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEST_STRING "Hello, World!"

template <int N> struct xtmp2 { typedef char (&t)[N]; };
template< class T, int N > typename xtmp2<N>::t xlen( T (&)[N] );
#define STRLEN(x) (sizeof(xlen(x))-1)

int main( void ) {

  printf( "strlen(\"%s\") = %i %i\n", TEST_STRING, STRLEN(TEST_STRING), strlen(TEST_STRING) );
}
```

As to macro debug, its possible to get a preprocessor output (like gcc -E);
it may be also helpful to undefine most macros, then enable them one by one to
see what happens.

Comment: why not use a template function rather than a macro ?

Comment: It won't be a constexpr then - eg. you won't be able to define an array with strlen size. Actually in this case its more interesting why I can't return a char array without that typedef.

Comment: unless you specify that the function returns a `constexpr` ?

Comment: Yes, but then as well we can program in D or something; C++0x isn't worth the compatibility problems atm afaik. And anyway, there's no C++0x tag.

Comment: Wow, that's a really creative solution. I thought about trying to solve this using Boost MPL but I could not conjure a suitable template function. This solution is interesting in that it does not do any sort of recursive computation but merely measures the size of the defined type. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please forgive me if this is an irrelevant pointing out.
The predicate for `BOOST_PP_WHILE` is evaluated while preprocess.
However, if I understand correctly, `MACRO_IS_NULL_IMPL` determines whether
the character is `'\0'` at compile-time(runtime?).
So, I think it is difficult to accomplish the goal directly with string
literal `"Hello, World!"`.

Comment: actually, I think that you are write :) The application of `[]` to a C-String is evaluated at runtime (to begin with) and so is the evaluation of `==`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks! That's really encouraging :-D

Answer (score 3):

It won't work, and for a simple reason: the preprocessor is not meant to deal with literals.

The preprocessor only knows about "tokens", it can catenate them, it can transform one into a string literal, and it can operate macros replacements, but that's it.

Here, the condition to stop the loop (use of `[]` and `==`) could be, at best, executed by the compiler (and most likely at runtime), therefore is not suitable for `BOOST_PP_WHILE`.

You can, actually, use the compiler to get the number of elements of an array (here an array of characters):

For example using `sizeof`: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. This can be abstracted in a macro, however it cannot become a "regular" function, since arrays cannot be passed to "regular" functions, only pointers (where you've lost the information size).

You can also use a template function:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

(this actually work on any array with a constant size)

But, for your own issue, you'll be pleased to know that most compilers have a built-in `strlen` implementation for constants that evaluates at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it was supposed to be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEST_STRING "Hello, World!"

#define STRLEN(x)    (x[0]==0)?0:TEST_01(x,1)
#define TEST_01(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_02(x,y+1)
#define TEST_02(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_03(x,y+1)
#define TEST_03(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_04(x,y+1)
#define TEST_04(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_05(x,y+1)
#define TEST_05(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_06(x,y+1)
#define TEST_06(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_07(x,y+1)
#define TEST_07(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_08(x,y+1)
#define TEST_08(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_09(x,y+1)
#define TEST_09(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_10(x,y+1)
#define TEST_10(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_11(x,y+1)
#define TEST_11(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_12(x,y+1)
#define TEST_12(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_13(x,y+1)
#define TEST_13(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_14(x,y+1)
#define TEST_14(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_15(x,y+1)
#define TEST_15(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_16(x,y+1)
#define TEST_16(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_17(x,y+1)
#define TEST_17(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_18(x,y+1)
#define TEST_18(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:TEST_19(x,y+1)
#define TEST_19(x,y) (x[y]==0)?y:-1

int main( void ) {
  printf( "strlen(\"%s\") = %i %i\n", TEST_STRING, STRLEN(TEST_STRING), strlen(TEST_STRING) );
}
```

But this isn't a compile-time evaluation, even though it would be usually
optimized to a constant.